# Reduce multiple calls to a greedy method

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, scope

I have the following JSF 2.0 beans:

```
@ApplicationScoped
class GreedyBean {
  Result doGreedyStuff(String userId) {
    ... // Takes lots of machine resources and time.
  }
}

@SessionScoped
class MyPageBean {
  String userId;
  GreedyBean greedyBean;
  String getFirstGreedyStuffStat() {
    Result result = greedyBean.doGreedyStuff(userId);
    return result.getString();
  }
  int getSecondGreedyStuffStat() {
    Result result = greedyBean.doGreedyStuff(userId);
    return result.getInt();
  }
  void setGreedyBean(GreedyBean greedyBean) { this.greedyBean = greedyBean; }
}
```

Then in my JSF page:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myPageBean.firstGreedyStuffStat}"/>
<h:outputText value="#{myPageBean.secondGreedyStuffStat}"/>
```

How do I refactor this to have only one call to `GreedyBean::doGreedyStuff` without implementing a cache mechanism by myself? If JSF can't do that, saying so is a valid answer.

**Notes:**

- I have barely any knowledge in JSF: I'm only fixing this one bug and then I resume my usual other tasks.
- We use Spring for the injection, I tried to translate those in JSF annotation. If there's an error there, please indulge me.
- As @JasperdeVries mentioned, I can't put the call in the `@PostConstruct` of `MyPageBean` because the data wouldn't be up to date. The result should be up to date at the moment of the request, not at the start of the session. I understand the principle and will enforce it, though it doesn't help me in *this* situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance issues when calling database in getter method for dataTable, getter is called multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669651/performance-issues-when-calling-database-in-getter-method-for-datatable-getter)

Comment: @JasperdeVries One notable difference is the mention of the scopes, I guess. I can't put those in the `@PostConstruct` of my session bean because it'd take too much time at that moment, also the data may be outdated if the session lasts for too long...

Comment: If you need the data to be request scoped, why not move it to a request scoped bean?

Comment: @JasperdeVries hmmm... Because I didn't know it existed (and there doesn't seem to be any request-scoped bean as example in the app I'm fixing). Thank you for that, I think I see the JSF under a better angle, now!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

From [@JasperdeVries](https://stackoverflow.com/users/880619/jasper-de-vries)' explanations, I need to add a new request-scoped bean:

**GreedyBean.java**

```
@ApplicationScoped
class GreedyBean {
  Result doGreedyStuff(String userId) {
    ... // Takes lots of machine resources and time.
  }
}
```

**MyPageBean.java** (should be renamed to something about the session, not the page)

```
@SessionScoped
class MyPageBean {
  String userId;
  String getUserId() { return userId; }
}
```

**MyPageRequestBean.java**

```
@RequestScoped
class MyPageRequestBean {
  // Beans
  MyPageBean myPageBean;
  GreedyBean greedyBean;

  // Data
  String firstGreedyStat;
  int secondGreedyStat;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    Result result = greedyBean.doGreedyStuff(myPageBean.getUserId());
    firstGreedyStat = result.getString();
    secondGreedyStat = result.getInt();
  }

  String getFirstGreedyStat() { return firstGreedyStat; }
  int getSecondGreedyStat() { return secondGreedyStat; }

  void setMyPageBean(MyPageBean myPageBean) { this.myPageBean = myPageBean; }
  void setGreedyBean(GreedyBean greedyBean) { this.greedyBean = greedyBean; }
}
```

**myPage.xhtml**

```
<h:outputText value="#{myPageRequestBean.firstGreedyStuffStat}"/>
<h:outputText value="#{myPageRequestBean.secondGreedyStuffStat}"/>
```